# Date format works fine locally but not while accessing live on Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, windows-server-2012-r2

I hosted an ASP.net MVC web application in Windows Server 2012 R2. It works fine when i run it locally but it raise an issue when i try to access it live. The issue is with the Date format. Locally when i send a date to a controller action method it takes it in MM/dd/yyyy format which is the exact format that i wanted but when i access it live (and i debug it through attaching w3wp process) it detect the date in dd/MM/yyyy format. I tried changing the Date Format settings of the server still same issue persist.

**Edit**
I am not using any specific date format through code

```
<input type="text" id="fromDate" class="form-control textbox" />
```

In javascript

```
var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
```

sending in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/MyAction',
            data: { fromDate: fromDate
```

[This is the date format in local and server both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNEnL.png)

[This is what i needed in my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5XjW.png)

Comment: how are you formatting the date in local machine?

Comment: check the culture settings on each machine. Better still, don't use ambiguous date formats. Pass everything around in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Or even better, send DateTimes around and leave all the formatting client side.

Comment: @oerkelens when you post back a form or make an ajax request (e.g. "sent a date to a controller action method" as mentioned in the question) that is done over HTTP, so at that point you have to serialise the date to some kind of text-based format.

Comment: Did you try parsing the date using: cultureinfo.invariantculture ?

Comment: I just have a simple question when my code is working fine through debugging in server, why it arise problem when accessing through live, when the code is same. Same code, same server, working locally but not live. Why??